# how to propagate error from the conv-layer to previous layer in Lenet-5 CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

Recently I'm trying to implement the Lenet-5 CNN. But I stuck in how to propagate error from the conv-layer to previous layer, for example, from C3 layer to S2 layer. Could anybody please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CNN typically have convolutional layer and pooling layer. Since pooling layer does not have parameters, it does not require any learning. Error Propagation in the last layer (FC) is same as NN. The only magic tricks involve in convolutional layers while having backpropagation. You can visualize the convolutional layers as a connection cutting NN [Transforming Multilayer Perceptron to Convolutional Neural Network](https://grzegorzgwardys.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/mlp-convolution-transform.png?w=640). The error can be propagated back by utilizing the equation [back propagation of delta error](https://grzegorzgwardys.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/cnn11.jpg).